# Update ALL bot commands without reloading it (without "node ." or nodemon)

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js, bots

I want to update my commands code without restarting bot fully using nodemon or just `node .` I wanted to make a command I can send to update all commands in my bot (basically commands collection where they are and their code stored). Here is the code I tried to use:

```js
const { glob } = require('glob')
const { promisify } = require('util')
const globPromise = promisify(glob);

await client.commands.clear()

const commandFiles = await globPromise(`${process.cwd()}/commands/**/*.js`);
commandFiles.map((value) => {
const file = require(value);
const splitted = value.split("/");
const directory = splitted[splitted.length - 2];
    
if (file.name) {
const properties = { directory, ...file };
client.commands.set(file.name, properties);
}
})
```

Result says my code worked but commands are not updating, how can I fix it?
Just in case: my djs version is v13.2.0

Comment: NodeJS is caching results of scripts execution from `require()` (also known as require cache). You should clear this cache. Maybe this answer will help you: [node.js require() cache - possible to invalidate?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11477602/16048617)

Comment: Might this work for your case? https://stackoverflow.com/q/24666696/15325967

Comment: @insyri he want to reload commands without reloading application at all. So he should clear the cache in that case and reload commands using `require` again.

Comment: Ah I see, I thought the goal specifically was to update the commands remotely.

Comment: @koloml It helped, but is there any way to get commands from `client.commands` and update them one by one, or maybe get commands using fs? (I have no idea how to do it using fs because I have category folders in `commands` folder)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using this function deletes the cache corresponding to the module/file and gets the updated version:

```js
function requireUncached(module) {
    delete require.cache[require.resolve(module)];
    return require(module);
}
```

Now, to require the files, just replace `require` with `requireUncached`.

You might however need to update on each event, to prevent it being updated late

```js
client.on("messageCreate", msg => {
  client.commands.clear();
  const files = fs.readdirSync("./commands") //read commands folder
  const folders = files.filter(f => !f.includes(".")) //get category folders
  for (const folder of folders) {
    const cmdFiles = fs.readdirSync(`./commands/${folder}`).filter(f => f.endsWith(".js")) //get cmd files in each folder
    for (const file of cmdFiles) {
      const f = requireUncached(`./commands/${folder}/${file}`) //require the file "uncached"
      client.commands.set(f.name, f)
    }
  }
})
```

There might be more efficient ways to do this, making sure that you don't have to update on each event